# How get Russian words from PDF-file

Tags: pdf, encoding, char, symbols

I use **pdfbox-1.8.2 for Java**, that read file electronic train ticket.

English words - is normal read.

Russian words - is **NOT normal** read.

How get normal **Russian** words from PDF-file?

[PDF-file example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oogmg52fioiwh3r/%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80.pdf)

[PDF-to-txt file example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/edd7xpzh7390wmc/pdf-output.txt)

Comment: The PDF does not contain the information required for regular text extraction of those Russian words, the fonts in question set the **IDENTITY-H** (i.e. essentially using some index in the font file) and don't offer a **ToUnicode** mapping. If you know the font used, you might succeed, though, by mapping byte pairs to characters using the font information.

Comment: Thank you. How can I find out what font is used?

Comment: Testing @mkl's suggestion: Plain text in document is: "ɗɅȿɄɌɊɈɇɇɕɃ/ȾɈɄɍɆȿɇɌ/ɄȼɂɌȺɇɐɂə/ɇɋȺȼ ɌɄɉ" -> list of Glyph indices: 599 581 575 580 588 586 584 583 583 597 579 (etc.). Looking these up in `cour.ttf` and translating back to Unicode indeed yields the plain text "ЭЛЕКТРОННЫ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helped me [more](https://gist.github.com/phpusr/9529689):

```
/**
 * Конвертирует строку состояющую из индексов Glyph, в нормальную строку
 * Для конвертирования используются индексы шрифта Courier New
 */
static String decodeString(String encodeMessage) {
    StringBuilder decodeMessage = new StringBuilder()
    for(int i=0; i<encodeMessage.length(); i++) {
        char symbol = encodeMessage.charAt(i)
        decodeMessage << decodeChar(symbol)
    }

    return decodeMessage.toString()
}

/**
 * Конвертирует символ, который получается из Glyph индекса, в нормальный символ
 * Для конвертирования используются индексы шрифта Courier New
 */
static String decodeChar(char symbol) {
    int symbolIndex = symbol as int

    String decodeSymbol = decodingMap.get(symbolIndex)

    //Для отладки: выводит индексы не распознанных символов
    if (DEBUG_MODE && !decodeSymbol) {
        println "null: $symbolIndex"
    }

    return decodeSymbol
}

/**
 * Создает хэш-мап соответствий индексов, символам
 * Часть символом записывается под Glyph-индексами, а часть под Unicode
 * (Так сделано потому, что в файле присутствоет и то, и другое)
 * Для конвертирования используются индексы шрифта Courier New
 */
private static Map<Integer, String> createDecodingMap() {
    Map map = [:]
    int startIndex = 0

    if (ADD_UNICODE) {
        //Добавление символов, записываемых под Unicode-индексами
        //В начале, чтобы индексы могли быть перезаписаны позже
        putUnicodeSymbols(map)
    }

    //Добавление разных знаков
    def otherSymbols = [3: ' ', 11: '(', 12: ')', 16: '-', 18: '/'] as Map<Integer, String>
    map.putAll(otherSymbols)

    //Добавление цифр
    def numbers = 0..9
    startIndex = 19
    numbers.each { num->
        map.put(startIndex++, num.toString())
    }

    //Добавление русских букв, сначало строчных, затем прописных
    def russianSymbols = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'ё']
    startIndex = 570
    russianSymbols.each { symbol ->
        map.put(startIndex++, symbol.toUpperCase())
    }
    russianSymbols.each { symbol ->
        map.put(startIndex++, symbol)
    }

    return map
}
```